# Переключатель языков на сайте

Tags: php

на сайте есть три языка, работает все нормально, НО при переключении языка всегда на главную страницу перекидывает, как это исправить?

```
<a href="index.php?lang=ua"><img src="images/header/h-ua.png" data-tooltip="українська"></a>
        <a href="index.php?lang=ru"><img src="images/header/h-ru.png" data-tooltip="російська"></a>
        <a href="index.php?lang=en"><img src="images/header/h-en.png" data-tooltip="англійська"></a>
```

Comment: Я даже боюсь ошибиться, но может стоит поменять ссылку?

Comment: @LLIAKAJI, а почему должно перекидывать куда-то ещё, если в ссылке явно указан `index.php`?

Comment: писал вместо индекса $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], но тогда параметр &lang приписывался столько раз сколько на него нажмут

Comment: Вместо этого пишите $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']

Comment: Вообще-то, достаточно убрать index.php, оставив только **?lang=язык**.

    <a href="?lang=en"><img src="images/header/h-en.png" data-tooltip="англійська"></a>

Переход будет на ту же страницу, но с добавлением параметра.

Answer (score 3):

Проблема в том, что скрипт не запоминает текущую ссылку.
Берете $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], берете $_GET, парсите get, заменяя $_GET['lang'] на то, что надо.
Потом при помощи http_build_url()
создаете новую ссылку и ее уже запихиваете в

```
<a href"
```

Comment: Чуть более простой способ, но он скорее костыль

    $uri = preg_replace('/lang=[a-z]{2}/','',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    if(strpos($uri,'?')!==false){
      $uri.='&lang='.$LANG_OF_CURRENT_LINK;
    }else{
      $uri.='?lang='.$LANG_OF_CURRENT_LINK;
    }
    <a href="<?php print $uri; ?>"><img src="images/header/h-ua.png" data-tooltip="<?php print $current_lang_name; ?>"></a>

Answer (score 0):

Может быть стоит хранить язык в сессии, а переключать на AJAX'е?

```
<div class="link" id="ru"><img src="images/header/h-ru.png" data-tooltip="російська"></div>

$('.link').click(function(){
    var lang=$(this).attr('id');
jQuery.ajax({type:'POST',url:'ajax/lang.php',data:{'lang':lang}});
});
```

ajax/lang.php

```
$lang=$_POST[lang];
$_SESSION[lang]=$lang;
// update page
```

langs

```
$lang=array(
'ru'=>array(
'welcome'=>'Добро пожаловать',
),
'ua'=>array(
'welcome'=>'Москаляку на гиляку, кто ни скачит той москаль',
),
'en'=>array(
'welcome'=>'Welcome',
),
);
```

index

> ```
> <title><?php echo $lang[$_SESSION[lang]][welcome]; ?></title>
> ```